# colorWithAlphaComponent not working in device ios 7

Tags: ios, popup, modal-dialog, segue

I want a pop up in my app. In the simulator the pop up is working fine and the background color of the view is also transparent.

But I don't know why I am not getting the transparent color in the device. In the device the background is completely black.

Here is what I have done in pop up screen:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
```

Kindly help. Please explain why I am not getting in the device

Thanks

Comment: Try this : ' UIColor *transBlack = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
self.view.backgroundColorr = transBlack.CGColor; '

Comment: I searched in google regarding this.. And I already tried it.. But it didn't work in my case